# Proving subsets of operation for three specific sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am relatively new to MathOverflow and my experience of Maths is somewhere between A-Level and University-Level.

In my further research, I came across the following question:

$$
\text{Given sets A, B and C : } C \subseteq B 
$$
$$
\text{Prove that: } A \cap C \subseteq A \cap B 
$$
Now, I went about trying to prove this, but felt like my argument wasn't particularly water-tight and moreover, I didn't possess the tools to make it so. My proof:
$$ A \cap C $$
$$ x \in A \cap C $$
$$ x \in A \text{ and } C $$
$$ x \in A \text{ and } x \in C $$
$$ \Rightarrow A \text{ and } (C \subseteq B)$$
$$(A \text{ and } C) \subseteq (A \text{ and } B)$$
$$ \text{therefore }A \cap C \subseteq A \cap B \text{   }//$$

I just get the feeling that this isn't entirely right. The notion is so simple but in a way I think that makes it strangely difficult to rigorously prove. Any possible feedback or help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Yours faithfully,
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in A \cap C$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. As $C \subseteq B$, we know that $x \in B$ (from $x \in C$). So $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, so $x \in A \cap B$.

This shows $A \cap C \subseteq A \cap B$.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense now. So I was close but missing a step, and shouldn't have treated the subset relationship as algebra.

Comment: Does this mean some proofs can contain parts that are inferred logically, rather than directly shown in full? Many thanks!

Comment: @Luke I don't see a difference. My proof is "showing it in full". You could also do it algebraically in a Boolean algebra way: there we have that $c \le b$ implies $a \land c \le a \land b$.

Comment: @Henno_Brandsma I see now. I am (clearly) rather new to formals proofs and have obviously over-thought the notion. Your answers make complete sense and thank you for taking the time to show me that. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

if $C\subseteq B$, and $A\subseteq A$, then $C\cap A \subseteq B\cap A=A \cap B$ even if that intersection $\emptyset$

Comment: Is it that simple to prove? Does it not need to be more thorough than that? Moreover, how did you arrive at that conclusion? I feel like you've made a leap somewhere that I haven't followed (and if you haven't, then mind expanding on your conclusion a bit?). Please bear in mind that I'm a pre-university student and the only exposure I've had to set theory has been relatively basic and without formal proof.

Comment: To expand on this, I guess my problem is that you've treated a subset relationship like algebra, but in a much more direct way than I did. How did you go from $$C \subseteq B$$ to $$C \cap A \subseteq A \cap B$$: did you make any kind of assumption?

Comment: if C is a subset of B, and A is a subset of A, then their intersection is one of a subset of B intersection with A.  subset of A  which would form a subset of the intersection of the full sets . Let B= $\{1,2,3,4,5\}; C=\{1,2,3\};A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$  the intersection of  A and B is B in this case. The intersection of C and A is C. C is a subset of B so the intersection of C and A form a subset of the intersection of A and B.  if one of A or C was the empty set the intersection would be the empty set. A set which in most versions of set theory I know is a subset of  every set. It follows.